# React-Native changing date format and showing it inside a <Text> tag

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'm able to show the "default" date with this format: Thu Jan 01 1970 01:01:00 GMT+0100

And i want to get this format: Thursday, 09 Jan 2017 06:00

Code i have so far: (Not written by me)

```
var date = new Date(customData[0].timestamp*1000);
// Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();
// Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
// Seconds part from the timestamp
var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();
// Will display time in 10:30:23 format
var formattedTime = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
```

If i call the variable "date":

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 01:01:00 GMT+0100
```

If i call the variable "formattedDate":

```
0:00:00
```

I call the variable using:

```
<Text style={textStyles.text_dies_mostrats}>{formattedTime.toString()}</Text>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Easier, take a look at moment.js

Comment: Your code works fine if you use just `new Date()` so I suspect there is some problem with your custom data, could you print just `customData[0].timestamp`?

Comment: customData is data from a JSON file, and the value of customData[0].timestamp is:  1488150000

Comment: It is working fine, take a look [here](https://jsbin.com/cefitusudi/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Could `customData[0].timestamp` be coming null or undefined?

Comment: You were right all along, it works just fine this code, but the timestamp points to the first second of a day, so: 00:00:00, and i thought it was badly coded. Can I upvote you or something?

Comment: I will post it as an answer!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a lab [here](https://jsbin.com/cefitusudi/edit?js,console,output) and your code is working fine.

I suspect that `timestamp` is coming null or undefined, or the time it is showing is the time it should show.

But your code seems to be working fine.